Unlocked Package with Experience components can never be uninstalled
Context:
An ISV Partner we consulted, working with a 1GP managed package, aimed to provide customers with an Experience Site that they could easily customize. To achieve this, they used an unlocked package to include Experience Cloud pages and components tied to their core managed package. This approach was recommended in Salesforce community resources, emphasizing flexibility over using Experience Templates. Key references include articles on Salesforce StackExchange and a related Medium article on packaging Experience Cloud sites.
Our issue:
However, this approach backfired significantly during testing. They faced severe issues when attempting to uninstall the unlocked package. Specifically, dependencies like ExperienceBundle, CustomSite, and Network prevented complete uninstallation. These entities cannot be fully deleted, only archived, which blocked them from uninstalling the package. Despite removing all dependencies, uninstall attempts still failed.
Salesforce Support got involved, and after considerable troubleshooting, they enabled the "Managed Component Deletion" permission and used internal tools to delete Managed2Package records. Despite these manual interventions, the issue remains unresolved, and the package cannot be cleanly uninstalled. There is still no standard user-level process for handling these dependencies, and even Salesforce Support has not found a definitive solution that partners or customers can use independently. This issue is tracked under Case ID: 468871428.
Additionally, during troubleshooting, the development team tried conducting a Proof of Concept (PoC) with an unlocked package that had a namespace, as well as an attempt to add a prefix to standard community classes and pages to make them custom. These steps were aimed at seeing if using namespaces or custom prefixes could mitigate the uninstallation issues. Unfortunately, these adjustments did not resolve the problem—indicating that the core issue with uninstalling these specific entities (ExperienceBundle, CustomSite, and Network) is not dependent on whether the package has a namespace.
We’re seeking insights from other partners—have you encountered similar issues with uninstalling unlocked packages for Experience Sites? Have you found ways to handle dependencies like ExperienceBundle, CustomSite, and Network that bypass the current need for direct Salesforce intervention? Any help or shared experiences would be greatly appreciated.
Support was able to make it work, but its still an internal issue to be resolved by Salesforce:

"We have an existing investigation for this and according to which, to
uninstall the package the Support has to enable the permission to
Managed Component Deletion, then delete Managed2Package records using
internal tool. Then at the UI you can go ahead and uninstall the
package."


Disclaimer: A related issue has been posted on StackExchange, but no resolution has been provided yet. You can find the discussion here: How to uninstall unlocked package that contains ExperienceBundle.

In a very high-level sense, being an unlocked package you can first delete the digital experience then uninstall the package.

(I must say I have never had the need to try the uninstall of such a package yet, so it's possible I've been glib with the above and that there is something in Salesforce that prevents the deletion of the digital experience first?)
